# Firefox not displaying Colorbox photo

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, colorbox

I have a colorbox which is supposed to display a single image on page load. The code below works well in Chrome. When I test it in Firefox, Colorbox pops up, but nothing is displayed (white). What am I missing?  I would very appreciate any help.

Javascript:

```
<script>
      window.onload=function openColorBox()
      {
          if(window.location.href=='http://somewebsite.com/')
          {
               $.colorbox({width:"70%", height:"70%", 
               html:"<div class='popupimage' id='popupid'> </div> "});
          };
      }
</script>
```

CSS:

```
#popupid {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   content:url(http://somewebsite.com/img/upload/popupphoto.jpg);
}
```

popupphoto.jpeg is on the server.

Comment: Try content:url('http://somewebsite.com/img/upload/popupphoto.jpg');
with " ' " i mean

Comment: nope, doesn't work :( @ThanasisGrammatopoulos

Comment: You tried it with the http:// ? because it was removed by mistake

Comment: yes, with http://.  @ThanasisGrammatopoulos

Answer (score 0):

After some testing it seems that Firefox has a bug in

```
content:url(http://somewebsite.com/img/ing.jpg);
```

For some strange reason firefox puts a space after the protocol in the url like

```
content:url('http: //somewebsite.com/img/ing.jpg');
```

and this prevent the browser from finding the image.
Test it here : http://jsfiddle.net/NKa25/

You can enter a local url of a copy of the image you want to load.

Comment: Thank you, @ThanasisGrammatopoulos, but local url did not work as well. I fixed this using img <src=url /> in html file.

Comment: Local works on my Firefox browser http://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_content_url

Comment: it might if you have only image name, but I need to add path to the image and that breaks it